# setup.py / pypi - Catching errors during installation

Tags: python, pip, setup.py

I am currently developing a command line application in python, which I will be uploading to pypi for end users to `pip install` and use. I am taking advantage of the `extras` functionality in `setup.py` to support 2 versions of my application, one is a basic functionality version with minimal dependencies and the other is more feature rich but has a large amount of dependencies (numpy, pandas, networkx, matplotlib, etc)

So briefly:

`pip install app        # simple, no deps
pip install app[all]   # all the deps`

Now the problem is that one of my dependencies in the feature rich version has what has been described as "flakey" pypi support. Basically, it cannot be installed unless one of its dependencies is already pre-installed before the whole installation process occurs. Luckily (or not), my application (which pulls in this flakey module) also has the flakey modules needed module. Lets refer to the module that flakey module needs pre-installed `fixer-module`

So:

`pip install app[all]     # triggers the installation of flakey module`

Installation will fail here if fixer-module is not installed, even though it will be installed before flakey module is. One must basically do this:

`pip install fixer-module
pip install app[all]`

Now what I would like to do is include some kind of checking code that accomplishes the following:

- Runs only when the `app[all]` distribution is being installed
- Does a `try import fixer-module, except ImportError` check and prints a message explaining the situation.
- Stops and cleans up the installation process before it fails

I have been researching this for quite some time. I found some examples of checking the input args to `setup.py` and whatnot but none of them seem to cover how to handle stuff during the end user install process. Any pointers are much appreciated!